# Geometric intuition of sentences in theories/models?

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory

All FOL models/theories share a common 'framework', this being FOL of course. That's why Henkin constructions, skolem functions, etc. work so well with no assumptions of the theory being modeled. However, most of the time the proofs of theorems use only one fact of FOL, that the cardinality of its sentences being the same as the language of the structure. In proofs, the are ordered them in some special way, and then the apply some procedure to each of the sentences and the end result is what was needed (using some properties of the deduction system too).

My (rather vague and open ended) question is, is there any better intuition/ordering of FOL sentences? For example, in Chang & Keisler's *Model Theory* they use the algebraic properties of boolean algebra and argue using properties of it's ultrafilter structure. Are there any other, easier-to-wrap-your-head-around, constructions? Is there any geometric interpretation of skolem functions? Elementary equivalent structures?

Comment: Why geometric? I can't claim that there are no such interpretations (though I don't know of any), but I can't imagine they would be more transparent.

Comment: Maybe other non geometric intuitions would be appreciated, but given that most of the time we are dealing with some kind of functions (skolems) or some kind of isomorphism (L-S) I think a geometric intuition would add a lot of value.

Comment: The question is indeed too vague - it's really unclear what you're looking for. When I think of "geometric intuition", I usually think of geometric intuition for the *definable sets* in a structure, not for the sentences. As you mention in the question, you can also use topological intuition when thinking about the Stone space (of ultrafilters / complete theories / types) which is dual to the Boolean algebra of sentences / formulas. What makes you think Skolem functions should have a geometric interpretation? Not all functions in mathematics are easy to visualize...

Comment: Also, I disagree with the claim that the only feature of first-order logic used in most proofs is the cardinality of the set of sentences. This is an important property, but hardly the most important. many other logics satisfy this property, while lacking other nice properties of first-order logic (like compactness for example).